# How does a lady Daven Tashlumin for Mincha if she never Davens Maariv?

Tags: halacha, women, mistakes, maariv, tashlumin

Suppose a lady who normally Davens (prays) Mincha missed Mincha one day. Now this lady never Davens Maariv. Must she Daven Maariv to do Tashlumin or can she just Daven one Shemona Esrei for the missed Mincha?

Comment: Will she listen if you tell her this night to daven maariv?

Comment: Or (a third option to your two), can she do _tashlumin_ at _shacharis_ (her next _t'fila_)?

Comment: @msh210 The OP never specifies if she ever Davens Shacharit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tashlumin always has to be *after* an ordinary obligatory prayer, so in your case in order to say the Tashlumin she would have to Daven Maariv first and then say the Tashlumin. (Halichot Shelomo Tefillah chapter 13 footnote יא‏)

While the above is I believe the more commonly held position, I note that [Rabbi Dr. Nahum Rabinovitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nahum_Rabinovitch) rules (Siach Nachum OC 10) [in the context of Friday night, but seemingly applicable at other times] that if a woman is stuck and can't follow the above recommendation, she can pray just once as Tashlumin and intend that if this can't be a Tashlumin it should be a Nedava (voluntary) prayer.

Comment: It seems from this  Mishna Brurah  (107:5) that on shabbas and Yom tov that there are no nedavas:{ה} מתפלת מוסף - ר"ל אפילו דשל ר"ח וחוה"מ כיון שאומר ומוספים כהלכתם והמוספין אינן קרבין אלא משל צבור ואין היחיד יכול לנדב אותם ועיין באחרונים שכתבו דלפ"ז בתפלת מוסף וה"ה בשבת ויו"ט בכל התפילות אם נסתפק אם התפלל אותם אינו יכול לחזור ולהתפלל אותם דהרי צריך להתנות וכנ"ל בסק"ב ובזה אינו יכול להתנות ועיין לקמן בסימן קכ"ד ס"א בבה"ל:

Comment: @sam Yes, I'm aware of that MB, and the responsum thus puzzled me. (I included the fact that the responsum was about Friday night in my summary here exactly in case someone here had a solution.)

Comment: My best guess is the RNR is sure enough of his psak to not worry about Bakasha on Shabbat, but wants to avoid risking Bracha Levatala. Something like that. EDIT: see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/126898/759

Comment: I am trying to understand how one can daven once and that is the tashlumim

Comment: @sam He argues that since we rule in the Machloket whether or not the Tashlmin needs to happen right after the next Tefila or any time later in the time of the next Tefila like the latter opinion, then the only requirements are that Tashlumin be in the right time and all other current obligations are dealt with. Since this woman (allegedly) has no obligation for Maariv, but is in its time slot, she's set. It's no different than if a man had already davened Maariv 3 hours ago and now it's 11pm and he remembers that he missed Mincha. (I agree it's a Chiddush, but interesting Lomdus all the same)

Comment: See too [Lehorot Natan 5:41](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14689&st=&pgnum=56) that since Maariv on Motzaei Yom Kippur is a Minhag, if you missed Neilah you can Daven Shemone Esrei once as Tashlumin for Neilah, and not worry about the Minhag of Maariv.