# Can one do double tashlumin

Tags: halacha, tefilla, shemoneh-esrei, orach-chaim, tashlumin

According to Halacha, if one misses both shacharit and minchah in the same day, can one do tashlumin for both at maariv? Or can one only do tashlumin for one Amidah?

Comment: https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Tashlumin#General_rules

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a major dispute among the Rishonim. Shulchan Arukh (OC 108:4-5) rules that only the most recent missed prayer is subject to the laws of Tashlumin, but one can, and it is proper to do so, pray additional voluntary prayers in place of all the other ones missed.

Comment: +1. But not on Shabbos, when voluntary offerings are not brought ([Rambam, Hilchos T'filla 1:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Prayer_and_the_Priestly_Blessing.1.10?lang=bi)).

Comment: @Fred Some acharonim indeed recommend that, but others explicitly allow this on shabbat as well

Comment: @Fred https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/126885/did-rav-hai-gaon-pray-maariv-twice-on-friday-night-when-the-tsibbur-prayed-befor/126898#comment417969_126898

Comment: Interesting. My impression is that general consensus among modern-day Ashkenazi poskim is that practically one does not pray a nedava on Shabbos. That's the position of the Mishna B'rura (107:5), and R' Chaim Kanievsky and Rav Soloveitchik ruled that way as well.

Comment: @Fred Pretty much no one ever prays nedava ever, so it's no real chiddush or puk-chazi/proof from minhag. In our case here though there is a tzad that this isn't a regular nedava so there is more reason to allow it, and indeed some pretty regular ashkenazi acharonim (magen avraham, beir heitev) do.

Comment: People do n'davas nowadays, just usually if there is some  reason (like a safeik tashlumin where it's a n'dava 'al t'nai and they add something to the prayer). And I was referring to expressly stated positions (not puk chazi). But yes, as you mention there are Ashkenazi acharonim who permit it on Shabbos (see also R' Akiva Eiger who discusses a potential distinction between Musaf and other Shabbos prayers).

Comment: @Fred Those are all safek nedava. I meant no one prays vadai nedava. In the case of safek, as I mentioned, there are lots of reasons to be lenient about shababt, especially depending how strong the safek leans in one direction. Consider something like https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/57739/how-does-a-lady-daven-tashlumin-for-mincha-if-she-never-davens-maariv/57741#comment181827_57741

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks.