Why does the Shulchan Aruch allow a Tefillas Nedavah on Motzaei Shabbos?
The Shulchan Aruch (Orach Chaim 108:11) brings down a case where one should pray as a Nedavah on Motzaei Shabbos, because of a doubt.
My question is: how can one pray as a Nedavah on Motzaei Shabbos, being that Korbanos cannot be offered at night, and there cannot even be leftovers of a Nedavah from the day, being that Nedavos cannot be brought on Shabbos, and we therefore don’t pray as a Nedavah on Shabbos (Orach Chaim 107:1)?

This is a clever question, but note the whole idea of limiting nedava based on korbanot is a minority opinion of unclear origin so it's not surprising we wouldn't always take it to it's full logical extension, eg https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/140380/759

Another similarly clever argument about Eivarim would lead one to say you can't pray arvit at all friday night since the eivarim had to be done before shabbat, cf https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%92%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%94%D7%9D_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%A1%D7%96

I think the fallacy here is comparing a nedavah of maariv to the burning of the eimurim of a nedavah brought during the day. But wouldn’t it be more comparable to volunteering to be maktir the korbanos that have already been brought that day? If true, a nedavah of motzaei Shabbos is essentially volunteering to burn the eimurim of the Shabbos korbanos.

Here are two possible answers that I thought of:

While it is forbidden to offer sacrifices at night, one is still allowed to consecrate an animal at night, which cannot be done on Shabbos.

The Gemara (Zevachim 120a) brings an argument between Rav and Shmuel as to whether one was allowed to offer a sacrifice on a private altar at night, before the Beis Hamikdash was built, and according to Rashi, Rav is the one who permits it, and the Halacha is generally like Rav, aside for when it comes to monetary laws.



The simple answer could be, at night no korbanos were brought at all, only eimurim. So just like the eimurim of chovos were brought so too eimurin of nadavos were brought as well and therefore you can daven nadava.
